# Data analysis in other scripts - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm very new to R Shiny and so far I've been doing any data cleaning/analysis in my `ui` and `server` scripts so I only have to run one thing. For example, things like setting up `popups` for `leaflet`, filtering data and creating reference tables... they all start to add up.

This looks and feels messy to do, so my question to you is:

Is there a way to run other scripts when the app is run? Or, what is the standard procedure if data cleaning/analysis/setup needs to be done prior?

Just here to learn!

Comment: This is a bit vague, but some thoughts before this question is closed as needing focus: (1) `source(.)` on another `.R` file will run its contents, and in the same environment as the caller (meaning that objects/variables can be shared, though I urge the use of parameterized functions to be safer); (2) `callr::r_bg` can be used to spin something off in another R process, and you can periodically poll it to see if it's still alive and/or harvest its value; (3) the `processx` package (used by `callr`) is a more generic way to call "something" in the foreground or background.

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! I'll look into all of these!

Comment: Using shiny it depends on when you want to execute your "other scripts". If you want to run your scripts on app start e.g. use `global.R`. Please check [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html). Furthermore, you can put those scripts into a `R` folder in your shiny project root to have them sourced on app start - see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/loadSupport.html).